# Fortran I/O: Adjusting RECL parameter of an already OPEN-ed sequential output file

Tags: fortran

Is there a statement or a way to adjust the RECL parameter in Fortran for a sequential, formatted output file that has been opened? Or do I have to close the file and reopen it with the new RECL as the only way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

No, such characteristics can only be specified in the OPEN statement.